# Flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am designing a chat application from flutter for android devices, but when I added a plugin for firebase authentication, It gives the following exception. I am accepting an answer from you. Thank you in advance!

`Flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)`

Here is the code in the Registration screen

```
  class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;
  .
  .
  .

  onPressed: () async{
          try {
            final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password);
            if(newUser!=null){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
            }
             }catch(e){
              print(e);
          }
          },
```

Here is the code in Chat screen

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

@override
void initState(){
 super.initState();

getCurrentUser();
}

void getCurrentUser() async{

 try {
  final user = await _auth.currentUser();
  if (user != null) {
   loggedInUser = user;
   print(loggedInUser.email);
 }
}catch(e){
print(e);
}
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you add where and how you created _auth object ?

Comment: Okay, I updated the code, including that where I created the _auth object

Comment: can you try this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14137#issuecomment-429150844?

Comment: if you add plugin and do not give full restart then also you may face same error, so try to give full restart to your app.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, When I give a full restart it's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After adding new plugin and adding new assets it is recommended to give full restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem with pod installation during a full restart, try the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and check the deployment target of the app (currently the minimum version required for various firebase services is 10)
2. Then navigate to the `ios/` directory in the terminal and run `pod install --repo-update`

U can check for the ios minimum required versions [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/ios/#ios-supported-versions)